# Angular 4+ with typescript using Bootstrap project mono repo

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, bootstrap-4

I would like to practice on a project which is already set up with Angular 4+ using Typescript and a Bootstrap template. It will be great if I only need to run npm install and ng serve to get going. Any mono repo suggestions will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look at [angular cli](https://cli.angular.io/) and include your bootstrap on your css folder.

There are better structures if you use node, but angular cli only creates a basic and clean front-end template to start.

Comment: Thanks.. I wasted like 3 hours to edit and develop from a project I found somewhere on git.. Was just looking for a decent one as I don't really have time for unnecessary troubleshooting while there's templates out there. Plus  I'm lazy af lol

Answer (score 0):

I found this vid on yt which was exactly what I needed (I'm still noob mkay): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEvzW_sSXk0